# TableView image misaligned after swipe to delete

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode6

My table view cell appears misaligned after swipe.

[image: screenshot]

Here's tableView function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
        deleteItemFromCart(indexPath)
    }
}
```

I am using custom cell which looks like this with constraints:
[image: custom cell]

I had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689067/custom-cell-in-uitableview-shifts-right-after-swipe-to-edit), but it didn't help me.

Comment: there might be some thing with your constraints

Comment: @SyedAliSalman Some probable issues?
Do the constraints break after edit mode?

Comment: Yes, view breaks constraints while animating

Comment: Then how can I realign it correctly? How does every app do it?

Comment: It depends on how you want them. Can you send me your .nib file